# Grouping query results where values are not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that recreates the row names into column names on the second query. Ideally will have two queries by using temporary tables are implementation. I have the first query like this:

```
select * from scores;
```

Giving me this result

```
EmpID  Class    Amount
1      First    200
1      Second   300
1      Third    400
```

Desired results:

```
EmpID  First    Second   Third
1      200      300       400
```

Query tried so far

```
select EmpID,
(case when p.DeductionName like '%First' then Amount else null end) as First, 
(case when p.DeductionName like '%Second' then Amount else null end) as Second,
(case when p.DeductionName like '%Third' then Amount else null end) as Third
from scores;
```

This one gives such a result

```
EmpID  First    Second   Third
1      200      null      null
1      null     300       null
1      null     null       400
```

Am now struggling on how I can get the desired output i.e.

```
EmpID  First    Second   Third
1      200      300       400
```

Answer (score 4):

use conditional aggregation

```
select EmpID,
max(case when p.DeductionName like '%First' then Amount end) as First, 
max(case when p.DeductionName like '%Second' then Amount  end) as Second,
max(case when p.DeductionName like '%Third' then Amount  end) as Third
from scores group by EmpID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
select t1.EmpID,
   sum(coalesce(t1.Amount, 0)) as First,
   sum(coalesce(t2.Amount, 0)) as Second,
   sum(coalesce(t3.Amount, 0)) as Third
from scores t1
left join scores t2 on t2.EmpId = t1.EmpId and t2.DeductionName like '%Second'
left join scores t3 on t3.EmpId = t1.EmpId and t3.DeductionName like '%Third'
group by t1.EmpId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot command in sql server

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT F.ID,F.RK,F.VAL
    FROM 
    (
        VALUES('1','First ',200),
        ('1','Second',300),
        ('1','Third ',400)
    )F(ID,RK,VAL)
)AS D
PIVOT(SUM(D.VAL) FOR D.RK IN ([First],[Second],[Third]))
AS PVT
```

Comment: OP is using MySQL-

Comment: The <sql> tag stands for the SQL _language_, not the MS SQL Server _product_. Different products have different SQL implementations. The functionality you use here isn't supported by MySQL (AFAIK.)